# Enhanced Notes Email

Tags: trigger, email, workflow

I am looking for the best way to Send an email when an Enhanced Note is added to a specific record.

For example, user opens a record from custom orders object, adds an enhanced note, at this point an email is sent out to specific users.

I tried using Email workflow but the "Notes" is not available as an object.

Any other ideas? Maybe a Trigger?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a trigger on insert on the [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) SObject. You would send some [SingleEmailMessages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) to the specific users, either by adding them as 'To' addresses or CCing them on one SingleEmailMessage or by sending one to each recipient with setTargetObjectId() set to the user or contact receiving the email.

The benefit of doing it the second way is that it is not counted against Salesforce's [limit for single email sent using apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section) to 5000 external email addresses per day. However if you do not believe you will be sending enough mail to hit that limit, the first way is simpler.

An example of sending an email to multiple people at once:

```
List<String> emailAddresses; // This list should be be populated with user's email addresses
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage objEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
objEmail.setSubject( 'This is the email subject' );
objEmail.setHtmlBody( 'This is the body of the email' );
objEmail.setToAddresses( emailAddresses );
Messaging.sendEmail( new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{ objEmail } );
```

Comment: Hello Kyle, do you have a link for sample code, mainly around how do I limit the trigger only for a certain object? I am looking for the one single email to multiple specific users.

Comment: Hi @MicroSumol, I edited my answer to add an example of sending the email however you will need to do some learning outside of the scope of this answer on how to write triggers. To get you started, I recommend this trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro

Comment: Hello Kyle, thank you for the information. I was wondering if there was something specific for the related records that needed to be taken into consideration. I will give it a try. Thank you once again.

Comment: You might want to consider that instead of actually sending the emails via apex using messaging.sendEmail to instead: Create a related record and use workflow alert to send the emails.  At some point you might run into platform limitations around number of emails that can be sent.